# $\sum_i^k |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i^k |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|$?

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

Why does the equality $\sum_i^k |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i^k |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|$ holds?

Shouldn't the limit be inside the sum? And the by the convergence of $f_n$ to f, the equality holds. Is it correct?

*Theorem:*
Let ${f_k}$ be a sequence of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ such that for each $x\in [a,b]$ $f(x)=\lim_{k\to \infty}f_k(x)$. If there exist $K>0$ such that $V(f_n,[a,b])\le K$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, then $f$ is bounded variation on $[a,b]$.

*Proof:*

Let $a=x_0<\cdots<x_k=b$ be a partition. Then 
$$\sum_i^k |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i^k |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|.$$
Since the variation is the supremum you have
$$\sum_i^k |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|\le V(f_n,[a,b])\le K$$ for each $n$ and so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i^k |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|\le K.$$
This shows that
$$\sum_i^k |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\le K$$
for **every** partition $a=x_0<\cdots<x_k=b$ of $[a,b]$. Hence, $K$ is an upper bound and so by the definition of supremum of a set you get $V(f,[a,b])\le K$.

Comment: We have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_i^k=\sum_i^k\lim_{n\to\infty}$. Note that the partition (and $k$) is fixed.

Comment: So the equality holds because the partition given and k are fixed? @RobertZ

Comment: Yes, it fllows from the fact that the limit of a finite sum is the sum of the limits.

Comment: got it, thank you @RobertZ

Comment: the sum is finite and the absolute value is a continuous function, then by the algebraic properties of the limit of a convergent sequence $(g_n)$ we have that $$\lim_n\sum |g_n|=\sum|\lim_n g_n|$$

Comment: 'the absolute value is a continuos function' I didn't know that, weird fact :D @Masacroso